# Lightning web Component send query string to Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning-web-components

When I was redirecting my page like this, then it was working perfectly fine the current Order Id I was getting from the method after clicking the button Pay now button

```
<div slot="footer" class="slds-align_absolute-center">
 <lightning-button variant="brand" label={payNowText} icon-name="utility:moneybag" class="slds-m-left_x-small" onclick={payByStripe}>
 </lightning-button>
</div>

payByStripe(){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: 'https://sandbox-fun-java-6633-dev-ed-176cc1dd4e4.cs90.force.com/wedgy/checkoutPayment?orderId='+this.order_id
            }
        },
        true
      );
}
get order_id() {
        return this.cart.orderId;
    }
```

But when I do this

```
<div slot="footer" class="slds-align_absolute-center">

<iframe id="vfFrame" src={vfHost} height="650px" width="770px" style="border: 0px"></iframe> </div>
```

and concatenate this order in my Vfhost then it doesn't load

```
vfHost = 'https://sandbox-fun-java-6633-dev-ed-176cc1dd4e4.cs90.force.com/wedgy/checkoutPayment?orderId='+this.order_id;
```

but when I changes the vfHost URL to something like this:

```
vfHost = 'https://sandbox-fun-java-6633-dev-ed-176cc1dd4e4.cs90.force.com/wedgy/checkoutPayment?orderId=jkahdajk585'
```

then it works.
The only thing changes that I removed the earlier button and inserted an iframe.
I am actually very confused in this how can I get this done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only show or load the iframe once the `orderId` is avialable.

So have a `template if:true{orderidIsAvailable}>` or `<div if:true{orderidIsAvailable}>` then have your iframe inside this.

```
<iframe id="vfFrame" src={vfHost} height="650px" width="770px" style="border: 0px"></iframe>
```

JS as :

```
get orderidIsAvailable(){
    return !!this.orderId;
}
```

This will load iframe only if `orderId` is populated.